translating: We are eating a lot of watermelon
My answer was "Nous mangeons beaucoup de la pastèque" as pastèque is feminine.
Duo lingo says "Nous mangeons beaucoup de pastèque". Why is my version incorrect?
Thanks

You’d probably be better off with a rewrite along the lines of Nous mangeons de grandes quantités de pastèque.  Word-for-word translation often fails, and indeed it often makes it possible for native speakers to guess your native language from peculiarities in its syntax and expressions.

Your answer translates back to We eat a large part of the watermelon, which is not the original meaning. The gender of pastèque is only a side problem here. Welcome to fr.SE, anyway.

Here is a simple rule that works in almost all cases:

After beaucoup de, (un/très/si/...) peu de, trop de, assez de, suffisament de, pas mal de, un kilo de, un morceau de, etc., don't use an article.


Nous mangeons beaucoup de pastèque.

The only exception is when what you are referring to is specific.
That means your first sentence is not technically incorrect, just very unlikely to be used like would be "We eat a lot of the watermelon", i.e. a lot of that particular watermelon.
See also: Quelles expressions françaises avec 'de' sont fixes ?
